# Songplay (no.2)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, music

I believe the previous `Songplay` riddle was too easy, today I'd like to share another great song and as with the previous `Songplay`, the idea is for you to figure out what song it is and who it’s by. Good luck to you all!

---

### The Rules

- The riddle has to match the original rhymes.
- The riddle has to stay with the original flow of the section you choose.
- You must explain what the song is about as best you can.
- Subtly giving away the artist or title is fine.

---

### The Puzzle

Today's song is a great part of American history! I will offer up $50$ reputation to receive a creative answer.

> Let me share a tale, of how 29 brave men drowned, in a tale of misfortune quite spumy.
>
> I wish, it was said, the lake gives up her dead, when the skies up above her turn gloomy.
>
> Going back home, with tons of iron in store, weighed more than the ship did when empty.
>
> Her good hearted crew, was tough through and through, when the gales of the winter came early.
>
> The captain rang in, for the ship was done in, and his good ship and crew were in peril.

---

### What is the song, and who is it by?

Comment: It's by Lights Poxleitner-Bokan? The acronym says 'light'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This song is

> The Wreck of the Edmund Fitzgerald, by (Canadian) Gordon Lightfoot!

Comment: So in order to stump you up, I have to do a more modern song lol Great story and fantastic song! I knew this one was too easy too. LOL

Comment: @PerpetualJ it did help that some of the lines were almost exactly what I remember the actual song to be, but it’s hard to change a lot of the words and still have them fit the music. Great puzzle though!!